# create equations from lines in image in python 2.7

Tags: python, image, detection, equation, image-recognition

What python library would be useful in creating an equation from an image of straight edges. Something that would take an image, divide it up into a xy grid, recognize that there is a straight line and find the linear equation of that line with respect to the xy grid.

What I plan to do is detect the two sides of a rectangular shape and calculate the equations of the perpendicular lines. I don't need any code but the names of some relevant imaging libraries would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [OpenCV's Cascade Qualifier](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier).  It is a C library, runs on most platforms, has a python interface and can be used to detect different shapes.  I believe it is what many websites use to detect faces in photos.  I had looked into it as a way of automatically generating 3d building models from photos.